# Can't figure out how to make this JSON Valid?

Tags: javascript, json, validation

So I have a piece of JSON here that's coming up with errors in my IDE

```
"title": "(Microsoft Word - Tez butun hal\375nde.doc)",
```

It says illegal escape sequence and I suppose it's the backslash. But removing the backslash or trying other escape sequences isn't working.

How do I make this JSON Valid?

Comment: http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: why downvote, people? :/ Everybody has their first time. I personally have seen the effort of OP.

Comment: Have you tried by removing backslash ?? is that necessary. Or you can try by escape that like "title": "(MicrosoftWord-Tezbutunhal\\375nde.doc)" .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The backslash is reserved for escaping characters, so to input a proper backslash: `\\`

```
"title": "(Microsoft Word - Tez butun hal\\375nde.doc)",
```

Escaping means you can input special characters you can't without the escape character. When the string is parsing, `\\` will be regarded as a literal `\`, so no worries on extra text.

To make your whole document valid, check all your `\` entries and escape them properly :)

---

Here's something outside this question's scope.

How to input `"` within `""`? You escape the quote with `\"`. Like so:

`"something": "He said, \"Hi!\""`

Here's a list by Microsoft listing escapable characters: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2yfce773(v=vs.94).aspx

Comment: I've +1ed, but it's interesting that OP notes in the question that "*removing the backslash [...] isn't working*"...

Comment: @Jeroen perhaps there are other backslashes or syntax error